# WordPress Visual Mode Not Working - adding span code while clicking

Tags: visual-editor, wp-editor

After the update of WordPress 4.9.6, I got a very strange issue that I am not able to write anything in WordPress editor in visual mode.

When I'm trying to switch from text to visual I am getting this span code instead of text.

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 
0;" data-mce-type="bookmark" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue? I am not able to write anything.

Comment: Are there any errors or messages in your browser dev tools console?

Comment: No, I checked in the console and also network there is no error

Comment: Sorry, I am getting this error,

     Uncaught TypeError: e.on is not a function
         at Object.e (plugin.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:1)
         at zm.c.fire (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
        at Object.fire (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
        at new YC (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
        at n (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
        at Array.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
        at At (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
        at e (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
        at Re.y.bind (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)

Answer (score 0):

I disable JetPack and everything is working.

Comment: And you had the exact same problem as the original question? Can you explain why JetPack broke visual mode in the first place?